# How to reconstruct the signal using overlapping frames in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, audio, time-domain, array-signal-processing

I understand that we can use the `buffer` function in matlab to split a long signal into overlapping frames. But is there any functions that we can use to put the frames back to reconstruct the signal?

Here's my current code in Matlab

```
n = 0.1:0.1:100;
y = sin(n*pi*0.5)';
Nw = 100;  % window length
Nh = 25;   % hop size
Y = buffer(y,Nw,Nw-Nh, 'nodelay');  % Y is the matrix containing the overlapping frames
```

What I want to do next is to use Y to reconstruct the original signal y. Something like this

```
yNew = unbuffer(Y, Nw, Nw-Nh)
```

Of course there is no such function as `unbuffer`, not that I've known of. So my question is, is there any function available to do the job of `unbuffer` ?

The situation is similar to this question here: https://www.reddit.com/r/matlab/comments/361y9w/reverse_buffer_function/, which was 5 years ago and still received no answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do any overlap and arbitrarily large vectors while being fast it is a bit cumbersome.

If you only do 50% overlap, then it is straight forward to write an unbuffer function

Answer (score 0):

[unbuffer](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/master/ssqueezepy/utils/stft_utils.py#L141) in Python; [helpful post](https://gauss256.github.io/blog/cola.html). Nice visuals in [MATLAB docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/istft.html) (bottom).